# Running Sql server Stored Procedure with excel parameter and without using VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, parameters

I would like to excecute an sql server stored procedure with a date parameter from excel, the date parameter is an input in a cell of the spreadsheet.
Is it possible to do this without using VBA ? 
My goal is to get dynamic results every time when i set a new date value in the excel file and the examples that i found are using vba when it is about using the dynamic parameters from the excel file.
Please help if there is a way to do that without vba.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Start by using Microsoft query to set up a connection to your database, and as the desired number of parameters... Parameters can be added by putting conditions on the query and entering [] in the value box.

Finish creating the connection then edit the connection, and change the SQL to:

Dbo.procedurename ?

The question mark is placeholder for parameters. Link the parameter to cell, and set it to auto update on cell change and your good to go.

Comment: thanks i used microsoft query as you told me and in the connection Properties defenition i put in the command text exec db.mystoredProcedure '2018-03-23' , and the result is displayed correctly in my sheet, now i want to link the value that i enter in the date cell be passed as parameter of my stored procedure, how can i link this value to be the parameter , when i change the value of the cell date i hope to see data relative to this date, i see examples in the net thet we can define parameters from cell and specify the cell, but in my example the Parameters button is disabled,any help please?

Comment: You need to add parameters in the Microsoft query gui. So just select some random table and put a filter (value []) on it to start with. This is the only way to get parameters in the query

Comment: Microsoft Query seems to no longer be a choice as an input in Excel 365.
Does anyone know what the new way to use one or more excel cells as a constant list filter for records?  I will also ask as a new question.